# Epandframework security module configuration

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I am using XAF from devexpress, I just added the security module from the expandframework and all my navigation disappears for non administrative users.
Am using XAF's new security system all well configured even navigation.Is there
extra configuration that am unaware of in expandframework?(am new to the expand framework)

Answer (score 0):

The info you posted is not enough to determine this behavior. For each [eXpandFramework](http://expandframework.com/) module there is a set of tester solutions located @ https://github.com/expand/eXpand/tree/17.2/Demos/Modules I suggest you look how the SecurityTester solution is configured and try to see what might differ. SO is not the best place to post such questions as there are [dedicated forums](http://www.expandframework.com/forum/) and I happy to help you if you post a sample demonstrating this case there.